# Binding to add on a backbone.js collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'd like to set a model's ID to the correct value after a fetch in all instances of a backbone collection, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
var NoteCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend(
{
    model: Note,
    initialize: function () {
        this.bind("add", function (note) {
            if (!note.id && note.has('noteid'))
                note.id = note.get('noteid');
        });
    } 
});
```

The function never gets called (I'm testing by creating a new NoteCollection and calling fetch on it), what am I doing wrong?

Note: I know I could bind the method on a specific instance of NoteCollection, and that works, but I want to bind it on *all* instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because note.id is returning true.

The good news is Backbone already has a convention to set the model's `id` property to a specific attribute on the model. This is done by setting the `idAttribute` (See [this line](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L233) in Backbone's source)

```
var Note = Backbone.Model.extend({
  idAttribute: 'noteid'
});
```

With this code, Backbone will take care of setting `note.id = note.get('noteid')`